# Forgot password to FileVault. Still got access to the machine

Tags: macos, security, filevault

I just realized, that few months ago I converted my disk to FileVault. I am afraid of loosing access to my data. I still have access to the machine: login, password, administrator account.

Is there something I can do to protect myself against loosing data? Like burning the key-cd in Windows?

Comment: which version of OS X? FileVault or FileVault2?

Comment: @lupincho: OSX Lion 10.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things that can decrypt a FileVault volume are

1. the **passwords to your user accounts** that you gave access during FileVault setup, and
2. the **recovery key** (24 characters) that you received (and should have written down) during FileVault setup.

If you no longer have the recovery key, and you're concerned about forgetting/losing your account password, you can go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > FileVault` and click `Enable Users...` to allow more user accounts to decrypt the volume.

Alternatively, if you don't want other accounts to have that ability, you can disable and then re-enable FileVault to get a new recovery key (but that may take a long time).

Comment: Wow so no problem actually, as I remember the user password. Thanks!